# How to get data out of try catch block?

Tags: java, android, json, exception

```
final ArrayList<String> pic = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jobj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            name.add(jobj.getString("name"));
                            pic.add(jobj.getString("pic"));
                        }
                        txt1.setText(name.toString());
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {                        }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    txt.setText(pic.toString());
    mQueue.add(req);
```

`name.toString` in try is not empty(ex: [a,b,c,d]),but if i move this out of try like `pic.toString` array is empty (ex:[]).

Comment: first of all: fix this -> catch (JSONException e) {                        }
How do you know whether an Exception is thrown there? answer: currently, you don't. First figure out whether your code works as you expect it does.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?? Please clarify your question first

Comment: One difference is that `name.toString()` is inside the listener that will be called eventually while `pic.toString()` is outside. The listener will _eventually_ fill the list (when it is called) but `pic` is accessed right after creating the listener.

Comment: JSONObject jobj, when you create an object in try, you can only use it in try. Initiate Object before the try/catch block and you can use it in the whole function. Put it in the class, you can use it in the whole class.

Comment: i want to use these data to set a list

Comment: If your list is empty, ensure that both "adds" are actually called. i assume it always throws some sort of error, so you arent able to fill these lists. Because creating the list outside of try block and populating it inside, is how you get data out of the try block.
besides, are you sure that onResponse is called before text.setText(pic.toString()) ?

Comment: @Daniel B ,Yes. Because  txt1.setText(name.toString() works!

Comment: that doesnt mean the loop executes. checked if response.lenght == 0?

Comment: I add Log.d() in try and name.add(jobj.getString("name")) is true. 
And response.lenth not equal to zero.
If I change txt1.setText(name.toString()) into Log.d("TAG",name.toString()).
There are right data that I actually need in name arraylist.But if I change
txt.setText(pic.toString()) into  Log.d("TAG",name.toString()).
name array is empty.
My English is pretty basic.I don't know whether you could understand what I mean.But still thanks a lot!